# Preload all images in a directory using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, directory, preloading

I want to preload all images in a directory called `img`,and that directory also contains sub directory called `ui_images`.

I know how to preload specific images by putting their names in an array and doing the preloading work, but i want to know how to tell the script to search dynamically for all images in that directory `img` and `img/ui_images`?

Here's my code :

```
var preloadImg = function(imgArr){
    $.each(imgArr, function(index,value){
        $("<img/>")[0].src = value;
    }); 
}

var arrimg = ['img/check.png','img/add_sub.png'];
preloadImg(arrimg);
```

Comment: There is no way to do this. At least, no good way. Http offers nothing like directory listing or anything like that. So the client would have to basically try every possible file name. What you can do is have your server code investigate the directory and dump all the files into a JS array that jquery consumes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no generally available facility for doing a directory listing in http.  The options I can think of are:

1. Name your images in a predictable fashion like (img001, img002, etc...) and then you can load images until you get an error.
2. Name your images in a predictable fashion like (img001, img002, etc...) and then code in one numeric limit value into your web page for how many there are.
3. Create an ajax call (on both client and server) that will give you a list of image names to preload.
4. Have your server embed an array of image names into the page so you know what to preload.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay - It you're using an `<img>` tag, then it would be the `error` event on the image object.  Instead of the `load` event, you'd get the `error` event.  If you're requesting the data via an Ajax call, it would be a 404 status.

Comment: I use `img = new Image(); img.src=url;`

Comment: @yukashimahuksay - Then, you can use `img.onerror(fn)` or `img.addEventListener('error', fn)`.  For any more info on this, you should write your own question rather than continue commenting here.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking at improving the performance on one of my sites and looked into this. My solution seems to work and I haven't seen it anywhere else yet.

Its a two step approach using jquery and php

1. // Preload images via jquery .load and delete once their cached via the callback

   ```
   <div id="preload"></div>

   $('#preload').load('preload.php', function() {   
   $('#preload').remove();   
   });
   ```
2. // preload.php below - loop through the image folder and insert the images into a hidden div

   ```
   <div style="display:none">
   <?php
   $dirf = 'images';
   $dir  = scandir($dirf);
   foreach ($dir as $file) {
   if (($file != '..') && ($file != '.')) {
       echo "<img src='images/$file' />";
       }
   }
   ?>
   </div>
   ```

This worked in Firefox but feel free to critique or improve